# Write a function that returns the coordinates of an available spot for a vehicle or returns False if there is no spot

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

There are three kinds of possible vehicles: regular cars, small cars, and motorcycles.

Regular cars can only park in R spots. Small cars can park in R or S spots. Motorcycles can park in R, S, or M spots.

Also uppercase indicates that the spot is available and lowercase indicates that the spot is taken

```
spots = [
    ['s', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's'],
    ['s', 'm', 's', 'S', 'r', 's'],
    ['s', 'm', 's', 'S', 'r', 's'],
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 's'],
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 's'],
    ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'm', 'S']
  ]
```

So i am guessing I have to loop over the spots list to start off, so this is what I have:

```
for i in spots:
        if not i.isupper():
            return False 
    return True
```

I keep getting the list has no attribute 'isupper' error which I understand why but I don't know how to fix it, let alone move forward with the rest of the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please print `i` inside loop and check the result. The error message explains clearly what it is.

Comment: You could add a second for loop inside the first one. One more thing, I guess you are just omiting writing `def ` rather than using return outside a function

Comment: `spots` is a list-of-lists, so `i` is a sublist.  You need another nested loop to access the elements inside `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`spots` is a **list of lists**. Therefore, when you are looping over `spots` with `i`, each `i` is also a list. You can verify this by having `print(i)` at the beginning of each loop.

If you want to access each individual spot (letter) in spots, you must use **another loop** within the first loop, similar to the following:

```
for row in spots:
    for spot in row:
        if not spot.isupper():
            return False
        return True
```

I hope this helps!